# Get current post id from front end via ajax wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post

```
function sendIdToFrontend(){
  global $post;
  $postId = array('post_id' => $post->ID);
  die(json_encode($postId));
}
```

This is my ajax function, I am at single post page. Where I've button which triggers this function.
But I'm unable to get the post id. Is there anything wrong with this function ? I'm getting "null" in response.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,     
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {'test': 'test', action: 'checkCorrectAnswersViaAjax'},
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Where is `$post` defined? Do you get `post_id` back with a value of NULL or no response

Comment: Why not use `echo`? `die` returns a string

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I just need the code snippet which can help me to get current post id on button click (button is present on single post page).

Comment: When you send an ajax request WP doesn't really know anything about a 'current' post. This is a separate request not associated with any post. You need to send your post_id with as part of the request and use it at your backend.